# How to calculate cost for selected items on page load - JS & Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am able to display the name, price and fetch the quantity previously entered into the database.  On page load, i want the script to calculate the total by multiplying the price and quantity of each selected item and adding up the sub-totals of each item to get the grand total.

how can i achieve this?

```
<div class="panel_container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">    
    $( document ).ready(function() {

    @foreach ($items->products as $product)
        var product = $('#{!! $product->id !!}');  
        var selectedItems = JSON.parse(product.attr('data-products'));

        if(product.prop("checked") )  {
            $('.panel_container').append(
                '<div class="container">' +  
                    '<p class="name">' + product.name + '</p>' +
                    '<p class="price" data-price="' + product.price + '">' + product.price + '</p>' +
                    '<p class="sub-total"><span class="sub-total" name="sub-total" id="sub-total"></span></p>'+
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control quantity"  placeholder="qty" name="quantity[]" value="{!!$product->pivot->quantity!!}" required/>'+
                '</div>'

            )

        } else {
            //clear selected item    
       } 
    @endforeach     

    calculate();
});

var sub-total = 0;
var calculate = function() {
    var ship_container = $('.panel_container').closest('div');    
    var quantity = Number($('.quantity').val());
    var price = Number($('.panel_container').closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));    

    ship_container.find(".sub-total span").text(quantity * price);

}

</script>
```

Comment: You mind specifying programming language of `@foreach` stuff?

Comment: @entio  this is laravel , please

Comment: Where's your trouble coming from? Your calculate function kind of makes sense, you just have to run it for each product `<div class="container"/> i guess`

Comment: @entio , when i run this code, it duplicates the sub total of the first item for the rest of the selected items as well

Comment: oh, yeah, sub-total needs to be set to zero before every iteration of the loop, right? Cause for each group (container/product) it is different, should be calculated from null. And grand-total should be initialised (set to zero) only once.

Comment: @entio, where do i set to zero, i don't get you please. can u use code to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code must be modified to run for each product.

```js
var grandTotal = 0;
var calculate = function() {

  // for each product
  $('.panel_container .container').each(function() {
    var product = $(this),
      quantity = Number(product.find('.quantity').val()), // get quantity
      price = Number(product.find('.price').data('price')), // get price
      total = quantity * price; // calculate product total

    product.find('.sub-total span').text(total); // show product total
    grandTotal += total; // add to grand total
  });

  // use the grandTotal here..
  alert('Grand total: ' + grandTotal);
}
```

Additionally, `id` attributes are required to be unique in the html so you should remove the `id="sub-total"` from the loop.

Comment: thank you very much. it worked but you left out `.`  when referring to the class `product.find('sub-total span')` :)

Comment: @Switz you are correct. updated answer with the missing `.` :)